# If $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ is it also $O(g(n-d))$?

Tags: asymptotics

When trying to prove that a recurrence $g(n)$ satisfies $g(n) = O(f(n))$, we sometimes are not able to find a valid $C$ to show the upper bound, so we try to prove it is $O(f(n-d))$ for some constant $d$ instead.

If we are able to prove that $g(n) = O(f(n-d)$, does this mean that it is also $O(f(n))$? 
If so, does this go the other way too? That is, if $g(n)=O(f(n-d))$ for some $d$, then $g(n) = O(f(n))$ as well?

edit 1: 
Here a valid $C$ means, $C$ such that $f(n) <= C*g(n)$ for all $n > n0$ for some $n0$

Comment: What is "A valid $C$"? Please don't assume that everybody uses exactly the same notational conventions that you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question (whether $f(n) = O(g(n))$ implies $f(n) = O(g(n-d))$) depends on the function $g$: indeed, what you want holds iff $g(n) = O(g(n-d))$. This is a relation that holds for many functions, for example polynomials and exponentials, but not for the function $g(n) = 2^{2^n}$.

As for your second question, if $f$ is monotone (increasing) then $f(n-d) \leq f(n)$, and in particular $f(n-d) = O(f(n))$. The same holds if $f(n) = \Theta(h(n))$ for some monotone $h$. For example, if $f$ is a degree $a$ polynomial then $f = \Theta(n^a)$, and so $f(n-d) = O(f(n))$, since $n^a$ is monotone.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't imply this if $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are functions with wide swings, like $f(n) = 1$ if $n$ is even and $n$ if $n$ is odd, $g(n) = 1$ if $n$ is even and $n^2$ if $n$ is odd. Clearly $f(n) = O (g(n))$, because you compare large values of $f$ with large values of $g$, and small values of $f$ with small values of $g$.

But if $d$ is any odd number, and $n$ is odd, then $f(n) = n$ and $g(n-d) = 1$.

Another case is that even when $f$ and $g$ are monotonic, both might grow so fast that $g(n-d)$ becomes arbitrarily small compared to $g(n)$. Take for example $f(n) = g(n) = 2^{2^n}$.